Nodemailer not working in nextjs say's Module not found: Can't resolve 'stream'
Module not found: Can't resolve 'stream'  https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
Import trace for requested module
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:

./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mime-node/index.js

./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mail-composer/index.js

./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js

./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js

./app/api/contact/route.js

I go through there documentation but not found any solution for this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you didn't clarify your source code but ı guess the problem is coming from edge runtime code in your root layout. İf you need to use edge runtime in your project you can still delete it from your root layout incase you need to add


export const runtime = "edge"



this line to every page.js in your project.
